# DataView RowFilter not selecting any rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a GridView that gets populated from a DataView as the source.
When I try to filter rows based on the RowFilter of the DataView nothing happens.

I have a textbox that allows users to enter an Item_Number to search for and should select the records from the DataView that only contain that Item_Number.

```
public DataTable PrintTable
{
    set{Session["PrintTable"] = value;}
    get
    {
        if(Session["PrintTable"] == null)
            return null;
        else
            return (DataTable) Session["PrintTable"];
    }
}

public DataView PrintView
{
    get
    {
        if (PrintTable != null)
        {
            DataView  dv = new DataView(PrintTable);
            dv.AllowEdit = true;
            if(SortAscend)
                dv.Sort = SortColumn;
            else
                dv.Sort = SortColumn + " DESC";
            return dv;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Private void BuildGrid()
{
    daUnSched.SelectCommand.Parameters["@WC_Id"].Value = WC_Id.Text;
    daUnSched.Fill(dsPrintTicket2.SFD10011);
    PrintTable = dsPrintTicket2.SFD10011;

    dgPrintTicket.DataBind();

}

private void btnGoTo_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{            
    string val = GoTo.Text.Trim();
    if (val.Length > 0)
    {
        PrintView.RowFilter = string.Format("Item_Number = '" + val + "'");
        PrintTable = PrintView.ToTable();
        dgPrintTicket.DataBind();
    }
}
```

When I enter an Item_Number and press search, the btnGoTo_Click method gets called, but its not selecting the rows based on the RowFilter.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you are not assigning Datatable back to your GridView before binding after filter; `dgPrintTicket.DataSource = PrintTable;` before `DataBind()`

Comment: @techspider I tried that as well and didn't work. When I debugged the program I checked the value of PrintView.RowFilter and it was "" blank.

Comment: It will never blank as per your code; as long as you have some value in `val`.

Comment: I do have a value in val. I checked it and its there.

Comment: Then there is no way your `string.Format` doesn't return value

Comment: not sure if it is something to do with having no `set` on your `PrintView`

Comment: you logic looks messy :(

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned `DataTable` back to the `GridView` to show filtered results

```
private void btnGoTo_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{            
    string val = GoTo.Text.Trim();
    if (val.Length > 0)
    {
        PrintView.RowFilter = string.Format("Item_Number = '" + val + "'");
        PrintTable = PrintView.ToTable();
        dgPrintTicket.DataSource = PrintTable; //Or assign DataView
        dgPrintTicket.DataBind();
    }
}
```